# Deleting nodes from an xml

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

From the below XML, I want to remove the start and end tag for `<root>` so that `<INVOKE>` becomes the top level node.
Also the `<item>` tag is to be removed in such a way that `<DNAME>`,`<PEMAIL>` and `<PHONE>` becomes the child of `<PER>`

I found the solution for deleting the child nodes from https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html.
But the child node has to be deleted in such a way that the grand-child becomes the child node.

```
<root>
    <Invoke>
        <Set>
            <INT>
                <co>1</co>
                <ti>2</ti>
                <WOSTATUS>11</WSTATUS>
                <PER>
                    <item>
                        <DNAME>12</DNAME>
                        <PEMAIL>13</PEMAIL>
                        <PPHONE>14</PPHONE>
                    </item>
                </PER>
            </INT>
        </Set>
    </Invoke>
</root>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python xml.etree - remove node but keep children (assign children to grandparents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021298/python-xml-etree-remove-node-but-keep-children-assign-children-to-grandparent)

Comment: Thank You ..The 2nd part of the question is cleared. Could u please help me in resolving the 1st

Comment: The first part being removing `<root>` so that `<Invoke>` is the top level tag?

Comment: Yes that part only

Comment: I’m confused, isn’t it the same thing as the second part?

Comment: i dont think so because for example if i consider the node to be deleted as B, its parent as A and the grandchild as C, then in the link u mentioned they are deleting B and appending C as the child of A. But here <root> is the one to be deleted that is B, we have a C also in the form of <Invoke> , i dont have an A here right?

Comment: "How to remove root element from xml file using python?":  https://stackoverflow.com/q/34084658/407651

Comment: yes thank you soo much